# UI router update url based on $stateparams without reloading the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app there is a Table. Each row has an id associated with it. When I click on any row, the data of that row should be populated in a pop up form. It will remain in the current state only. But the url should change and should contain the clicked row ID also.

eg:

- Before clicking - **www.mysite.com/home/list/**
- After clicking - **www.mysite.com/home/list/1234**

---

```
"home.list": {
    "url": "/list/:record_id",
    "views": {
        "main@": {
            "templateUrl": "viewslistView.html",
            "controller": "ListController"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "displayName": "List"
    },
    "resolve": {
        "lazyload": {
            "dependencies":["resources/js/controllers/listController.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried updating the `$stateParams.record_id = 1234`, but it will update the $stateParams but wont update the url.

Tried `$state.go('list', {record_id:1234})`, it will update the $stateParams as well as the URL, but it will refresh the table view, which I dont need.

Tried `$state.transitionTo(...)`, but same result as `$state.go`

**My requirement is to update the url with the clicked recordID without reloading the view**